# Can I connect to multiple networks for double bandwidth?

Tags: networking, internet, network-bridge

If I used one wired connection to ISP_1 and another wireless connection to ISP_2, can Ubuntu benefit from both, such as running bit-torrent and getting twice the bandwidth?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, this is not possible.  You can connect to both ISPs at once, but each will give you a different IP address.  When you say, run a web browser and try to download something, it has to pick one IP address to use, and then its traffic will all be routed through that ISP.  You could run one program on one address and one on the other, but you can't get one download split across both links.

Comment: I assumed this would not be possible on a download from a server, but bittorrent you connected to multiple peers. Why not be able to give 2 address, some upload to one, some to other?

Comment: @Seth Kikari: in theory that is possible, but I do not know of any bittorrent clients that support that.

Answer (score 0):

To connect to two WiFi network at the same time, you have to have two WiFi modems in your computer. (Just like, you have to have two ethernet card to connect to two ethernet)

You may use an USB connected second WiFi modem.

If you have two modems and you've connected both, I think Ubuntu will automatically do load-balancing, and use both.
If not, it can be configured to do that, [maybe like there](http://www.tomshardware.co.uk/forum/21544-17-combining-multiple-internet-connections-home-network)

Answer (score 0):

Theoretically speaking, it should be possible, but it requires some advanced network configuration and has some caveats. [Server Fault has a question/answer regarding configuring a Linux router to do load-balancing between two ISPs](https://serverfault.com/questions/93678/load-balancing-nat-ing-multiple-isp-connections-on-linux).

In summary:

- You cannot split a single TCP connection between two ISPs. That's because a connection is tied to a pair IP+Port, and your IP address is different in each ISP.
- Although UDP does not have a "connection", the same restriction applies.
- Each new connection will be (randomly) allocated to one of the two ISPs.
- Since BitTorrent uses several parallel connections, you might notice a speedup there.
- Browsing the web might not work very well, because some sites tie your session to your IP address (in addition to the cookies), which means some sites will log you out because you are changing IPs.